# Mms-computing.co.uk twain library documentation

Tags: java, twain

I would like to use the mms-computing.co.uk.device.twain.jar library in a Java project that should talk to image acquisition devices.

I noticed that the site of mms-computing is unavailable; I could download the jar from another site but I can't find any examples or documentation about the methods exposed by that library and how to use them.

Can someone help me providing a link where the documentation is still accessible, if any?

Comment: Fabrizio, please don't sign your posts.  See the relevant section in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can see this link

http://thorntonzone.com/manuals/Compression/Fax,%20IBM%20MMR/MMSC/mmsc/uk/co/mmscomputing/device/twain/pdfapplet/index.html

This have many examples but few documentation.

I hope it will be useful to you.